# how many objects are created in the following code?

Tags: java

```
class ClassA {
    void h() { }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public static void main(String[] args){
       ClassA a = new ClassA();
       ClassB b = new ClassB();
  }
}
```

Yes, everyone think it's such simple and there must and definitely should be only two objects created.

But after I read the "Think in Java,2nd Edition", I think it may contain some more interesting thing here.

In "Think in Java", there is a sentence:" When you create an object of the derived class ,it contains within it a subobject of the base class.This subobject is the same as if you had created an object of the base class by itself."

It is in page 278 for 2nd Edition. You can also see it through this link "http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0065.shtml" (the section with big title "Initializing the base class")

Comment: Are you taking a job interview right now? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I took an interview this afternoon. I think there are five objects created, do you think so?

Comment: Which five would that be? I'm curious.

Comment: I think the question is, at what time?

Comment: 1> object a
2> a subobject with the type of Object when creating a
3> object b
4> a subobject with the type of ClassA when creating b
5> a subobject with the type of Object when creating b

2> and 5> because Object is implicitly the parent class for all class
4> because ClassA is the parent class of ClassB

Comment: very interesting question this..

Comment: what's the point to ask a question for which you already know the answer? Trying to get reputation? You should better ask about the differences between inheritance over composition.

Comment: Definitely,I don't know the answer and I am just confused. From the hot discuss, do you think I post this question just for reputation here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be 2. The `main` function is static so it doesn't need an object.

`ClassA a` is an object and `ClassB b` is an object

**EDIT**: ClassB doesn't consist of two objects because extends is an `is-a` relationship and not a `has-a` relationship. (ta mik)

**EDIT**: There is also the `String[]` object that is created by the runtime system, and potentially any number of string objects place within that array.  I am purposefully ignoring these but acknowledge their possible existence. (ta diveshpremdeep and Adam Goode)

**FINAL EDIT**: In order to determine how many objects are created (by the program, not the runtime system) you can use the `javap` program on the commandline like so (if test.java contains your example)

```
$ javac test.java
$ javap -c ClassB
```

output:

```
Compiled from "test.java"
class ClassB extends ClassA{
ClassB();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method ClassA."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class ClassA
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #1; //Method ClassA."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   new #3; //class ClassB
   11:  dup
   12:  invokespecial   #4; //Method "<init>":()V
   15:  astore_2
   16:  return

}
```

As you can see, there are only two bits of bytecode that are `new` (which creates objects I assume).  One for class `ClassA` and the other for class `ClassB`.  You can note that the `invokespecial` command is invoked afterwards to call the constructor, and also how class `ClassA`'s constructor is called from class `ClassB`'s constructor, but no new object is created inside the constructor (it is the default empty constructor).

calling `javap -c ClassA` shows an equally boring constructor which invokes the constructor for Object.

In summary: It is the `new` bytecode which creates objects on the heap, not the `invokespecial` which merely fills in the details of the memory allocated by the `new` bytecode.

Comment: but I think when creating object a,it will create a subobject with the type of Object,because it implicitly extends Object. The same as B.

Comment: No "subobjects" are created. ClassB is-a ClassA (but with extra B funkyness) rather has-a ClassA.

Comment: If is as what you say, then by what way can I prove that the subobjects really do not exist or be created?

Comment: higer: Theoretically, you could look at the heap, and you would find just 2 objects.

Comment: Can you tell me how to look at the heap? Debug in Eclipse?

Comment: As mentioned below, don't forget about the args array!

Comment: higer: Can you prove it? (Maybe he is right, but i don't think so)
Maybe some internal implementation of the JRE do it this way but from the language point of view there are no subobjects created.

Comment: Jarlac: Yes,thank you! Barkmadley show a good way to make me convinced.

Comment: barkmadley: thank you very much! I think I get the answer now.Hope you can accept my great thanks for your time to solve my curiousness .

Comment: @higer: about looking at the heap, check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

3 constructors being called to create 2 objects.

Comment: Where are 3 constructors being called? How can a constructor be called without creating an object?

Comment: Doesn't the true thing is there should a subobject with the type of its parent class created when creating one object?

Comment: higer: No. There are no subobjects due to inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean objects inside the `main` method block, then 2. This can be verified for example with a Java heap dump and the following code extension:

```
class ClassA {
    void h() { }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.in.read();
        main1(args);
        System.in.read();
    }

    public static void main1(String[] args){
       ClassA a = new ClassA();
       ClassB b = new ClassB();
  }
}
```

So:

1. Compile the class and run it. The program execution stops at System.in.read().
2. Find out the process id.
3. Run `jmap -dump:format=b,file=snapshot1.jmap PROCESS_ID`
4. Hit any key in the console to continue execution.
5. Run `jmap -dump:format=b,file=snapshot2.jmap PROCESS_ID`
6. Hit any key again to finish the program.

After that, you get two Java heap dump snapshots which you can compare.

I got the following values (with Java 1.6.0_15, OSX):

- snapshot1.jmap: 17584 objects
- snapshot1.jmap: 17586 objects

The difference is 2, which is also the number of created objects.

Comment: +1 for proving it. It'd better to mention that you can use command:          "jhat -J-mx768m -stack false snapshot1.jmap" to read generated jmap files.

Answer (score 2):

Two objects are created - an instance of ClassA and an instance of ClassB.

Calling new ClassB() does not call the main() method.  The default constructor, which is of the form

```
public ClassB() {}
```

will be used.  The same goes for ClassA.

Answer (score 1):

Only

## 2

Although `B` extends `A` when it gets created the constructor  in `A` is executed but at the end only one object out of `B` is created.

1`A` + 1`B` = 2 objects

As for:

> *"When you create an object of the derived class ,it contains within it a subobject of the base class.This subobject is the same as if you had created an object of the base class by itself."*

That means, the following is possible:

```
 ClassA a = new ClassA();
 a = new ClassB();
```

That is, you **can** assign an instance of B to a reference of type A, because:

> *"...This subobject is the same as if you had created an object of the base class by itself"*

That is what the ["is-a"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship is all about. You can say that "every B is-a A" and that's true.

What you **can't** do though is to invoke a method defined in `B` which is not defined in `A`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor, calls the super() (parent default constructor) constructor automaticly. So if you create a ClassB object a ClassA object would be created, too.

Comment: Nod. But others don't think so and there is not a convincingly way to make me clear about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be one of those questions your professor asks to make you think at an abstract level.

That being said I am willing to bet its 4 objects being created:

```
1) Class A

2) Class B

3) String[]

4) Since there is no such thing as a string array it is a char array.
```

Of course that is just a purely theoretical idea